# How can I resolve the URI::InvalidURIError in ActiveAdmin caused by moving my entire project to a new directory on my computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I just reorganized my computer and moved the location of a rails project to a different directory. Most of the app is still working, but ActiveAdmin is down.

The following URL: `http://localhost:3000/admin`

produces this error: `URI::InvalidURIError in Admin::Dashboard#index` in the browser, and the following error in the terminal: `ActionView::Template::Error (bad URI(is not URI?): "file-digest:///Users/correct_new_path/app/assets/javascripts")`

Comment: rake assets:clean ?

Comment: Nope - no change to the behavior